Why doesn’t Unity in play mode react on each button
I'm new to Unity and C# and I'm trying to create a platformer, I'm creating game controls for running right and left and for jumping, if running works well, then jump only responds to 1 press out of 5 for example. So I can't "spam" jumps. How to fix it?
Here’s the code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 8;
    public float jumpHeight = 13;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Flip();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(or 

I tried assigning another button to jump, but it doesn't help

if you read getkeydown it is only true on the exact frame it happens.. fixedupdate is not  every frame

Thank you very much, I add this part to void Update and it works perfectly, but I’m watching a video about creating the game and it was added to fixedupdate

well their swill suck :P yours wont :D

Does this answer your question? Is it really wrong to use Input.GetKey() on FixedUpdate? or this? C# Unity GetKeyDown() not being detected properly
